# Is it possible for my .net framework 4.8 application to run on a windows server .net framework 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have not been able to find an answer in MSDN or other resources on the net to this question.   My assumption is that I can't do it, just want to get confirmation.

I have an application that I run on a hosted windows server.  I do not have admin rights or any control over the server.  This windows server is running OS windows 2012 R2 / .net framework 4.5 (CLR 4)

The application that runs on this server is currently running .net framework 4.0

I want to upgrade the application from .net framework 4.0 to 4.8, to use some of the new features in 4.8 (namely samesite), which I can do on my laptop.

If I upgrade my application to 4.8 (in visual studio), publish it to the hosted server (running 4.5), will my application run?   or is the maximum I can upgrade to is whatever the server is running (v4.5)?

Thank for any suggestions, help.

Comment: If it use some of the new features, I don't think, it will work. But I suggest you make a simple testapp, using some of the new features and upload that for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to install the .net 4.8 runtime on that server computer. however, that should not be much of a issue if you have control over that server.

However, if this is a hosted solution and you not permitted to installer newer and later runtimes on that server? No, you cannot do as you ask. You have to re-compile your asp.net web site application as .net 4.0, or whatever is the latest version on that server.

So, either:
Install .net 4.8 on that target server.

or re-compile your app to 4.5, or whatever the highest installed .net is in that final server. So yes, the server needs to have the later .net runtimes installed. Barring that - you can't go higher then what that final server will or is to have installed for .net runtimes.